# How to provide vanilla labels (without any formatting) for ticks in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to create a simple line graph using plotly.js where the values in x-axes are somewhere in the range of 100,000.

To display the data, the layout I am using is as follows:

```
var layout = {
        xaxis:{
            title:"Numbers",
            tickangle:45,
            rangemode:'nonnegative',
            autorange:true,
            exponentformat: "none"
        },
        yaxis:{
            title: "Count of events",
            tickangle:45,
            rangemode:'nonnegative',
            autorange:true
        }
    };
```

And I am plotting the graph using this layout as follows:

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv',[sample_data],layout);
```

Earlier the tick labels were being displayed as 200k, 205k etc. After setting the "exponentformat" as "none", now the labels are displayed as 205,000 or 200,000.

I don't want any ',' here. Actually it would be best if there wasn't any formatting. Any help regarding how I can do this would be appreciated as I am very new to plotly and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any parameters in Plotly which makes sure that the labels are unchanged.
But at least it is very simple to overwrite the custom format and remove the `,`. You find all the ticks by looking for class `xtick` and then change the text.

```js
var data = [{
    x: [0, 10000, 100000],
    y: [1, 2, 3],
    type: 'scatter'
}];
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        type: 'linear',
        exponentformat: 'none'
    }
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

var g_ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.xtick');
for (var i = 0; i < g_ticks[0].length; i += 1) {
    g_ticks[0][i].childNodes[0].innerHTML = g_ticks[0][i].childNodes[0].innerHTML.replace(',', '')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```